# Reconnecting Messenger from Intent Service when activity restarted

Tags: android, android-activity, restart, intentservice, messenger

I am working on a applicatin that syncs with videos on server. It starts a IntentService that downloads playlist, inserts it into database and than downloads actual video files to sd-card.

I am using a messenger passed via intent when starting the service to communicate back how much % is already downloaded.

I works but obviously when activity gets destroyed and starts back again, the messenger doesnt reconnect.

What would be the solution to this problem, steer me into correct direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a messenger, you need to keep a reference to the handler created with the messenger that you passed to the intent service.

If the activity gets destroyed and recreated, that handler is still bound to the previous activity (which may also result in a leak).

One approach may be to have a reference to that handler inside a singleton object or inside the application object.

However, because of the asynchronous nature of intentservices, what I would do is notify the progress through broadcasts, so new activities may register to the same broadcast thrown by the intentservice. You never know if the service is still alive or has finished its job.

Using [localbroadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) may result in a more efficient solution.

Comment: actually, communication via intents is what I had in mind at first, however this is the first time I am doing this kind of communication, and have googled that messenger can be used for this and It seemed a better fit. Btw, is there any performance difference between the two? When should I use messenger instead? Thanks

Comment: I would say that messengers are more suitable for classic intents, which do not finish when they performed their task (at least, not by default). In that case you can provide to the only instance of the service a new messenger sending calling "startService" again. The onStartCommand of the only service will be called again with the new messenger. IntentServices on the other hand, must be seen as oneshot task executors, that expire whenever they finished their job. From a performance point of view I'd say there is a few difference IF you use a local broadcast as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: okay thanks, one more thing I would like to ask how often can I broadcast using local broadcast? Lets say to update every 0.01%, that would be 10 000 times in a minute or two, would that still be ok?